# Query inner object id in a collection using Firestore/ Angularfire2 or Firestore SDK

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me how to query `id` of `budgetGroup` object in `budgets` collection?

I can do a basic query like below. But how can I query an inner object as mentioned above?

provider.ts

```
 getSpecificBudget(id:string;budgetGroup: BudgetGroup, projectId: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Budget> {
    return this.fireStore.collection<Budget>(`projects/${projectId}/budgets`, ref => ref
      .where('id', '==', id)
    );
  }
```

model.ts

```
export class Budget {
    id: string;
    amount: number;
    contingency: number = 20;
    budgetGroup: BudgetGroup = new BudgetGroup();
    creationTime: string;
}

export class BudgetGroup {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    creationTime: string;
}
```

firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution.We can simply do as shown below. *i.e.* `.where('budgetGroup.id', '==', budgetGroup.id)`

```
getSpecificBudgetGroupBudget(budgetGroup: BudgetGroup, projectId: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Budget> {
    return this.fireStore.collection<Budget>(`projects/${projectId}/budgets`, ref => ref
      .where('budgetGroup.id', '==', budgetGroup.id)
    );
  }
```